# Would it be alright to house-rule in my game that Paladins can use Divine Smite on attacks with ranged weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, paladin, ranged-attack

Right now I'm DMing for an entire party of level 9 Paladins. We have the Paladin that is the Spank (rerolls 1 & 2), the Tank Paladin (has a AC of 19), and the Paladin Controller (uses mainly Buffs and Debuffs while attacking at other parts of the map). During our 1st session during Character creation our Spank was wanting to make a Ranged Paladin. I told him he could but would not be able to use Divine Smites.

What my players and I want to know is: **would it be alright to allow Divine Smites in the normal range of a Bow, Crossbow, etc. or should it be Magical Weapon that allows a Paladin to Smite at range?**

Comment: [Related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62520/22566)

Comment: [Related Crawford tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/999687210566729728): "Divine Smite works with melee attacks only because the paladin is traditionally a melee combatant (story angle). Divine Smite is generously designed partly because the paladin has to use it in melee, and melee abilities often pose a risk to the user (rules angle)." (This could form the basis for an answer, but isn't really an answer to OP's question on its own.)

Answer (score 30):

### My Experience with Ranged Smiting

I have created a magic item for my players that allows for ranged smiting. They are magical arrows that cost gold (I give my PCs the ability to craft magic items), and they deal smite damage on hit. In exchange for ranged smiting, however, the paladin must declare the smite and expend the spell slot for the smite *before* they fire the arrow. If the attack misses, the smite is wasted.

### Why I like this compromise

I feel like this creates a useful middle ground for the paladin. In play, she still goes for the melee attacks most of the time; only when the enemies are truly out of reach does she turn to the arrows. In effect, you are balancing the incredible versatility of a ranged smite with the possibility of wasting a spell slot, turning the smite into a ranged attack roll. Moreover, because firing the arrow requires DEX, your paladin has to make the same spellcasting stat vs. attack stat decision that they normally do. Finally, because they are consumable magic items, you can give out fewer of them if you think they're too strong, and there's an aspect of resource management to them as well.

Also, this makes sense in-universe: the Paladin can choose to use the smite from her weapon because she's always holding it, but if she shoots an arrow, she can only infuse it with the smite while it's in her possession.

### How this applies to your situation

Unlike your situation, my party was not all paladins. However, it's clear that even within your party, there are distinct specializations, and not all paladins will be able to benefit from ranged smiting. A dex-focused paladin would benefit far more than a str-focused paladin, for example, and it might feel unfair if the ranged paladin can do everything the melee ones can, but be out of harm's way as well.

Since your situation is unusual, I'd suggest phasing in smite arrows slowly. At first, you can introduce arrows that can only deliver 1st level smites. If those work out with the party, you can introduce arrows that are capable of higher level smites, as well as the smite spells. Ranged smites too powerful? Then give fewer smiting arrows. The ranged paladin's too weak? Then give more powerful arrows. Because the arrows are consumable magic items, you can easily "titrate" the ranged smite ability you give.

Comment: As regards your last section: thrown weapons not addressed. (Love the experience based answer as well as your reasoning).

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Good point. I'll just take it as a limitation to my suggestion, though, since I don't have any experience with thrown smite weapons.

Answer (score 8):

This is an interesting scenario. Generally I'd look at ranged smites--an unambiguous upgrade in the Paladin--and think about how it could cause your paladin to outshine other builds, spotlight, how to challenge them while not killing off others, &c. &c. &c. These are the problems that, in my experience, tend to crop up most when introducing homebrew into my games.

But none of that applies here.

Your pure-paladin party would all have access to this, presumably. There's no imbalance because they can all take advantage of it.

#### There are things to <strike>worry about</strike> watch for:

So what are the other issues that homebrews tend to cause?

You're making your party more powerful: it may be hard to challenge them, it may mean that challenging encounters are more "swingy" (as you're using high-CR creatures or large mobs).

This may be *too* good: if one paladin can deal their bursts at whomever they like while dancing away from too much targeting, all your paladins may find it irresistible to do so.

But you're never going to know until you try. Which means you need to have a conversation with your players about what they think of testing the option, what concerns they have, what sorts of things would be signs to them that this is awesome or crappy, and when you're going to have the next conversation about whether to continue the modification or scrap it. I *strongly* suggest you set that date before the first time you put it into play.

Answer (score 1):

Preface: RAW, [Smiting is intended for melee weapon attacks only](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62520/can-a-paladin-use-divine-smite-with-a-thrown-weapon). The following is going to be opinion based.

> **Would it be alright to allow Divine Smites in the normal range of a Bow, Crossbow, ect.**

This is very much up to the discretion of the DM. You have to ask yourself how much impact it will have if a character primarily built for frontlining in combat can instead drop Divine Smite nukes from 60ft away.

Personally, I would allow it. The factors I've considered are:

1. The damage output would be the same.
2. It adds diversity to a Paladin party.
3. The player would be taking the risk of separating themselves from the herd.

Whilst being able to nuke an enemy from afar would certainly be safer for the player, it also means that an enemy can sneak up and harass them without the rest of the team to help. I'd also consider restricting the player to light or medium armor if they want to use ranged smiting.

My reasoning is that giving the player the ability to smite at range is a pure power increase, and there needs to be a drawback somewhere. Perhaps the full plate armor is too bulky to negotiate a longbow with? Once again, up to DM discretion.

> **Should it be Magical Weapon that allows a Paladin to Smite at range?**

This is a good idea in my opinion, making the player work for their food. It also gives you the ability to customise the weapon(s) that they use for ranged smiting, adding disadvantages/drawbacks as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

**It should be allowed, but I would propose the following changes to the class**

- No heavy armor proficiency
- Fighting Styles as Ranger: Archery, Dueling, Defense and Two-weapon fighting
- Smite can be used at range and in melee
- Must say you are smiting before making ranged attack roll (love this suggestion above)

These are easy changes made at levels 1 & 2. Also, you are making the Str/Dex trade-off with ranged combat anyway and Dex paladins are already a good option.

Comment: On what do you base those suggestions?

Comment: Smite before the attack roll is mentioned above by Icyfire. As for the changes, the ranger proficiency and fighting style chassis just feels right for the other 1/2 caster warrior class. Anyone doing ranged smite home brew is probably going to convince DM to get Archery style anyway. A Nature deity like Sune' practically begs for her paladins to be more ranger-esque

Comment: It would be great if you add your reasoning to your answer and to [back it up with your experience](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8696/44723) of how this has worked out at your table :)

Comment: Smite is used after you know if you hit & best used after a critical. That's the strength. This gives full control to be able to use Smite most effectively. If forced to make the Smite declaration before the attack roll (like 3.X), you take away that and you have a chance to waste the smite, & spell slot, if you miss. The archery style will help mitigate misses, but fewer crits, and you also have cover and advantage on ranged attacks vs melee. As far as experience, I have none, just looking at it through mechanics and flavor. Elf Sune' pally w/bow makes more sense than plate wearing knight

Comment: I do appreciate the feedback @Akixkis . Please add if you think that's too unbalanced.

Comment: It might be confusing, but in short, melee will get far more damage out of Smite than ranged, especially over the career. Assuming both have the same bonuses to hit/damage, etc. This effectively cancels out, so you're left with damage difference on Smite on hit vs. Smite before attack roll.

Melee Smite crits 5-10% of the time, but after-the-hit choice means Smite damage can double 100% of the time on crit.

Ranged Smite declared before the attack will also crit 5-10% of the time, miss 30%+ of the time, and only deal double damage 5-10% of the time instead of 100% like melee.