# Can a rogue use sneak attack with weapons that have the thrown property even if they are not thrown?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, sneak-attack, throwing-things

For weapons like the spear that have the Thrown property, can a Rogue use sneak attack with them?
Thrown is considered a ranged attack and Sneak Attack specifies that "The attack must use a finesse or ranged weapon."
Does this mean a rogue could potentially apply Sneak Attack to an attack using a spear as it is technically a ranged weapon?  If so, would this also work if you were using the spear in melee?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62520/can-a-paladin-use-divine-smite-with-a-thrown-weapon

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 43):

## Sneak Attack does not work with melee weapons that have the thrown property, but lack the finesse property

The Rogue's Sneak Attack feature states:

> The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.

A melee weapon cannot simultaneously be a ranged weapon, because as the Weapons section (PHB, p146) states:

> Every weapon is classified as **either** melee or ranged.

In fact, a weapon must be listed in either the Simple or Martial Ranged Weapons tables to be considered a ranged weapon.

Moreover, the thrown property (PHB, p146) does **not** turn a melee weapon into a ranged weapon. It states:

> If a weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon to **make a ranged attack**. If the weapon is a melee weapon, you use the same ability modifier for that attack roll and damage roll that you would use for a melee attack with the weapon. For example, if you throw a handaxe, you use your Strength, but if you throw a dagger, you can use either your Strength or your Dexterity, since the dagger has the finesse property.

Making a ranged attack does not imply using a ranged weapon.

The thrown property allows you to make a ranged attack by throwing the melee weapon **despite it being a melee weapon**.

Whether or not you throw a melee weapon does not matter. If it lacks the finesse property, then it won't work with Sneak Attack.

Comment: +1 For thrown weapons are not ranged weapons. That is clearly the OP's misunderstanding and is absolutely the most important point.

Comment: "Making a ranged attack does imply using a ranged weapon." - I assume you mean "does not". I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: @V2Blast those pesky "not"s... I don't know how they always manage to get away.

Comment: Were you using the "Forget-me" nots by mistake? :P

Answer (score 16):

## No.  A thrown weapon is not a ranged weapon for Sneak Attack.

**TL;DR**: A melee weapon does not become a ranged weapon even if you throw it, nor does it count as a ranged weapon.

This is also discussed in [Miniman's answer to the question: "Are weapons with the “Thrown” property considered a “Ranged Weapon” for the purpose of sharpshooter?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/87566/38434).

Like Sneak Attack, another class feature that requires a ranged weapon is the Archery fighting style.  For that feature, there is a canonical answer regarding whether thrown weapons count as ranged weapons. Per the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), they do not:

> **Does the Archery fighting style work with a melee weapon that you throw?** No, the Archery feature benefits ranged weapons. A melee weapon, such as a dagger or handaxe, is still a melee weapon when you make a ranged attack with it.

So the spear in your example is not a ranged weapon, whether or not you throw it.